# Microsoft Word to PDF Converter

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, document-converter, microsoft-word

I am looking for a freeware to convert Microsoft Word (.docx or .doc) to PDF.

It would be nice to use this without installation.

I would like it to run on Windows and do not want any online converters - it must be on my computer.

Comment: How is it you'd like it to run "without installation"?

Comment: [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/de/downloads/oooportable.html) or [LibreOffice as portable version](http://portableapps.com/de/apps/office/libreoffice_portable) could do that, though that might be a little overkill ;)

Comment: Offline but without installation - means you are stuck with what you already have doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an **open source** converter which converts **Microsoft Word (.docx or .doc) to PDF**, and then I found Office To PDF utility that help you to convert you DOCX file into PDF. OfficeToPDF is a *command line utility* that converts **Microsoft Office 2003**, **2007**, **2010** and **2013** documents from their native format into PDF using Office's in-built PDF export features. To know more about Office To PDF visit the link:

**https://officetopdf.codeplex.com/documentation**

Comment: FYI, _Word is required to be installed for OfficeToPDF_

Answer (score 1):

#### MS-Word 2007+

What version of Word do you have?in any version after 2007, You should be able to click on "save as" and then, in the "save as type" section, you should be able to select pdf.

Comment: He said he's wanting something freeware.

Comment: As I just found out through [Office To PDF in TechMonika's answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/16784/12474), you can also save to PDF from MS Word 2007 with the [2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7).

Answer (score 0):

## [NW Docx Converter](http://www.nativewindsofmontana.com/software/docx2rtf.html)

docx2rtf v2.4, also called Freeware Docx Converter by NativeWinds, is a lightweight utility for Microsoft Windows for viewing and converting the following formats into .RTF and .PDF

> NW Docx Converter (formerly Docx2Rtf) is a feature-rich file
> conversion and PDF tool set.It's **free** and  As the name implies, **it can convert Word
> 2007 DOCX/DOTX to RTF or PDF format without installing Word**. However,
> Docx2Rtf has many more features including the ability to open, modify,
> view, print, and convert to PDF from many file types including
> LibreOffice SXW/ODT, HTML, RTF, Palm, PhotoShop, TIFF, PDF, and many
> more. Can rearrange and delete PDF file pages.

***see below how it works***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, I use the FOSS-software [**PDFCreator**](https://download.pdfforge.org/download/pdfcreator).
You don't have to learn how to convert a file, because it acts like a normal printer and so you can generate PDF-, PNG-, JPEG-, SVG-, TIFF-, PS-files and much more from every program with a print-function.

**But** you will have to install it.